# Shold post in Meta be required before closing a question?

Tags: discussion

When a question is closed votes where casted before.

Sometimes the voters can learn from this closed questions. While it is possible to ask on meta I'm considering if it will be possitive to **require** some sort of documentation of what the voters have learned from the closed question. Mainly to avoid encouragment to just dump users from the website by descrediting every useful idea they've had.

Not everybody wants to code but it can become clear to users how they can work along with Ubuntu's development.

Comment: Let's keep in mind this as well: If a user wants to get better reasoning from the community about why it was closed, they can open a meta post.  They can also flag for moderator attention if they think the post should be reopened (and they can justify why it needs reopened), and mods can evaluate whether it should or should not be closed.  However, it does *not help* to have meta posts for each question that is being closed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## No. Please, god, no.

Closing is for questions with severe problems content-wise. If five people (or a single mod) decide that the question is not editable into something good, we have the option to close it.

Close-voters can see exactly why other voters decided what to close a question as, and they can make their own decision.

We don't need a dedicated meta post for every question that needs closing. That would just be excessively silly and a waste of everyone's time and resources.

Now, if a post is contested by multiple people (and has a history of being closed/reopened) or users get into debates over "to close or not to close," then a metapost makes sense. But definitely not for every bad question.

Answer (score 8):

Honestly, I think it's pretty obvious this comes from your closed question about the tablet issues you were having, and the consequent Meta post about that.

> Mainly to avoid encouragment to just dump users from the website by descrediting every useful idea they've had.

I'm going to bring up a point that I (think) I brought up in my other answer. You are taking your personal experience and applying it to everyone else. Just because your question was closed doesn't mean your experience was exactly the same as others'.

In some cases, questions are closed because they're just off-topic enough to be put on hold. In other cases, like yours, the question is just blatantly off-topic, and the OP is a little rude and/or argumentative, seeming to not have read the rules of the site.

Before you go on Meta, ranting about how your "excellent" question (it really is not, at all) was closed for no reason (there was very good reason, which has been explained), and before you start making things up out of thin air ("mainly to avoid encouragment to just dump users from the website by descrediting every useful idea they've had"), **think**.

- What have you done wrong? ie, why was the question closed?
- What can you do to make the question clearer? (If English isn't your native language -- it seems like it's Spanish -- use a translator for some words you aren't sure about)
- Maybe the people who closed the question are correct? You don't seem to have actually read the Help Center or How to Ask a Question.

Don't just go off ranting. We're here to help, and you can see by our rep that people tend to agree with our solutions. If there are at least five people (the number it takes to close a question) telling you your question needs improvement, consider the possibility that maybe it does.

Maybe we aren't all ganging up on you because we have some secret agenda to destroy the SE-life of some random user. Maybe we're just trying to help, and you can't see that. Maybe your question isn't "useful," as you say. Maybe when five+ other users tell you you're wrong, you are. It's certainly a possibility, and 5+:1 odds make that possibility quite high.

---

To actually address this question directly, it's a resounding

## NO

Here's why:

Meta is the place for discussion, not recording close votes. Right now, the Close Vote queue is at 268 or so. If every single person posted that they CVed a certain question and their *specific* reason for it, Meta would get **so extremely cluttered it would drown out any useful discussion.**

Besides, we do explain our close votes. Have you checked the flag dialog, under the Off-Topic submenu? We have plenty of reasons to close the question, *plus the ability for custom ones if needed.* In short, we do explain our reasons for closing questions, and they can be clearly seen when the question is closed.

Again, you seem to be showing a blatant lack of understanding for the mentality of Stack Exchange, and an outright ignorance of Ask Ubuntu's site rules. To be frank, you sound arrogant, refusing to think that maybe the 5 people who disagree with you may actually be correct.

Now, we do willingly accept appeals for closed questions here on Meta, since we do sometimes get it wrong. However, your question is not one that will be reopened, at least without *significant* revision, grammatical correction and explanations of why it's about Ubuntu. In this case, we did get it right.

---

Please remember:

## We are here to help you

We aren't getting paid to do this. This is something we do in our free time, because we've decided that we enjoy helping others. If I joined to just be rude to every person who asked a question, I certainly wouldn't have 10k rep, and I would probably have been banned long ago.

This isn't Customer Service at Verizon; we aren't just trying to get rid of you so we can move onto the next customer and boost our stats. **We genuinely want to help.** The problem arises when users can't realize that not everything they say is perfect; not everything they say is understood; not everything they say is appropriate for the situation. This, I think, is where you are having trouble, and I know that sounds mean, but I believe it to be true.

Now, prove me wrong. Go improve your question and make it legible. Put a Spanish (if I'm right about the language) version along with the English one (in the same question). **I'll** translate it if you want. Just put in the effort to ask a good question, and we'll put in the effort to respond with a good answer.

"**It takes two to tango**"

Comment: I'll pay attention to this later. And stop using "refranes" if you are criticizing the use of personal experience.

Comment: We''l get  to that later

Comment: Sorry, what? I haven't used "refrain" once.

Comment: Zacharee didn't use refrain.

Comment: I think "refranes" is like "old sayings" which are cultural inheritance. And yes, this is the personal experience that is getting in the way of me and AU (what oldies have tauhgt us). I will simply make a PDF manual of the complete guidelines and will have it in Dropbox in case I need to acces it via other devices. So we can get this out of the way.

Comment: Sure... It's your choice.

Comment: @userDepth yes, I didn't realize you were using Spanish. However, I still don't see where I'm using sayings, except for the `two to tango` one, which is quite valid here.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Actually that's a question for Philosophy channels. I call it Mental modules. From there is you could be inspired to answer me this long response in a sentiment which you believe to be positive. Who knows if that should be screwed. But I consider other facts that would be too much if you are at work or something. Whatever else I'll be later @ chat if that's not out of topic.